# Substitute double backslash from input with single backslash in Lua

Tags: lua, escaping

Suppose I have the `str` variable, to which I assign the value `test\\ttest` (or it could actually just be `\\`, for this case). What I want to do, is substitute double backslashes with single backslashes.

The purpose is clear: I want to output the `\t` escape sequence (horizontal tab), while now it is just output as plain text `\t`.

It's also clear that I can't use:

```
str:gsub("\\","\")
```

Because that would cause a syntax error, being `\"` recognized as an escape sequence. I tried in all of the ways I could come out with. I also tried using loadstring() (and nested loadstring() calls as well) but it also failed.

Please, don't say to do:

```
str:gsub("\\t","\t")
```

Of course, it would work, but it's not what I need. I need to replace a double backslash with a single backslash.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you are being confused by quoting, because `string.gsub` can replace backslash characters:

```
C:...> lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> a="test\\\\ttest"
> =a
test\\ttest
> =a:gsub([[\\]],[[\]])
test\ttest       1
>
```

The backslash is used a as a character escape in double and single-quoted strings, but not in long strings written with the `[[...]]` notation. In the usual string constant, backslash consumes one or more following characters, and replaces the whole sequence with a single byte in the internal string value. So `"\\"` is a single byte string containing a single backslash, `"\"` is a syntax error, and `"\""` is a single byte string containing a double quotation mark.

Adding to the confusion is that Lua patterns as understood by `string.gsub` (and its siblings) use `%` characters for quoting and for naming special patterns. This is one of the more visible differences between Lua patterns and the regular expressions supported by other languages. To a Lua pattern, a backslash is just an ordinary character.

So when I set the value of `a` above, I used extra backslashes to get the string value to have two total. I could have written `a=[[test\\ttest]]` to the same effect. The call to `gsub` was written with the simple pattern that replaced doubled backslashes with singles. As can be seen, it succeeded and the result is the string `test\ttest` (along with a count of matches as the second return value).

In short, the substitution you as ask for in the question "just works" as expected.

But reading between the lines, that isn't quite what you wanted. It appears you are trying to convert the string `test\\ttest` to `test<TAB>test`. If that single conversion is what you wanted, then just write it as such:  `a:gsub([[\\t]],"\t")`. (Note that I used quotes so that the string literal *will* interpret the `\t` to mean an ASCII  character in the replacement value.)

The more general case is more difficult, because you not only have to handle the normal single-letter escapes for tab, bell, backspace, carriage return, newline, and so forth, but you also have to handle the one to three digit decimal code sequence.

**Update:** The temptation to write something that handles all backslash escapes as the Lua compiler does for string literals proved too strong.

```
function unbackslashed(s)
    local ch = {
        ["\\a"] = '\\007', --'\a' alarm             Ctrl+G BEL
        ["\\b"] = '\\008', --'\b' backspace         Ctrl+H BS
        ["\\f"] = '\\012', --'\f' formfeed          Ctrl+L FF
        ["\\n"] = '\\010', --'\n' newline           Ctrl+J LF
        ["\\r"] = '\\013', --'\r' carriage return   Ctrl+M CR
        ["\\t"] = '\\009', --'\t' horizontal tab    Ctrl+I HT
        ["\\v"] = '\\011', --'\v' vertical tab      Ctrl+K VT
        ["\\\n"] = '\\010',--     newline
        ["\\\\"] = '\\092',--     backslash
        ["\\'"] = '\\039', --     apostrophe
        ['\\"'] = '\\034', --     quote
    }
    return s:gsub("(\\.)", ch)
        :gsub("\\(%d%d?%d?)", function(n)
            return string.char(tonumber(n))
        end)
end
```

Such a function could prove useful if parsing user-supplied text and wishing to handle backslash escapes in the text supplied by the user. String literals should be handled by the compiler already.

Another caution is that if you find yourself with partially translated strings, you might actually be suffering from a lack of clarity of design. Actually needing a function like this outside of parsing user input is an indication that there might be a deeper problem with your design.

The function `unbackslashed` works by first replacing all recognized sequences that take the form of backslash followed by a single character with their equivalent numeric forms. A second pass converts all numeric forms into their literal characters. Two passes was required because the string patterns understood by `string.gsub` does not support an alternative notation as supported by a full regular expression parser. Otherwise the pattern to match could have been written similar to Perl's `/\\([0-9]{1-3})|\\(.)/` and the substitution performed in one pass.

Comment: In the first part you say how to replace "\\\\" with "\\". That's not what I asked, as you mention as well in the second part, in fact I do not want to output `\t` but an horizontal tab character. Your `unbackslashed` function is not what I asked either. Look up the OP, I explicitly said I didn't want to replace `\\t` with `\t`, but instead "\\" with "\".
However, I don't see the need of using ASCII codes and string.char() in that function, while merely using the ASCII characters like in `s:gsub("\\t","\t")` would work.
This is not the answer to my question, though.

Comment: If you want to output an actual horizontal tab character, then your string has to contain that character, not the two characters `\t`. The two character sequence is understood at compile time when it appears in a string literal formed with single or double quotes. The `unbackslashed` function emulates the Lua compiler's treatment of string literals, and can be used to convert a string containing a `\t` into a string containing an actual horizontal tab.